# React Native Image resizeMode='contain' not working

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-image

I can't get `resizeMode='contain'` to work for images loaded remotely, wondering if there's something I've done wrong.

Render Method:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.internal_button_avatar_container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.internal_button_avatar_image}
        source={{ uri: this.state.imageURL }}
        loadingIndicatorSource={require('../assets/icons/PageLink-Loading.png')}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Styles (relevant section):

```
internal_button_avatar_container: {
  marginRight: 10,
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
},
internal_button_avatar_image: {
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
},
```

I've tried `resizeMode='contain'` and `resizeMode='center'` but the image always is cropped around the outside of it's frame. [Screenshot showing cropped icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvHdm.png). I've also tried with `undefined` height and width on the image.

The cropping only appears to happen if the source image is not the same aspect ratio as the frame, a square source will result in perfectly scaled image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your situation, but I haven't problems with that in this snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@gersonmontenegro/resizemode

The original size of the image is bigger than the container, even it has a different aspect radio, and it has loaded according to the internal_button_avatar_image.

Is ok for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help, you made me realise that my code was right, so I went on to check the only other possibility, the source image...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was getting the image from an endpoint in an API that auto-cropped the original image - should've checked the source image before everything else!